# Get specific sentence in string

Tags: c#

please check image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPEi7.png), want to get text inside blue mark, So i have to remove "100", " ", "-" and " "

I have tried using regex it workS but it will remove also number inside sentence

```
private static string RemoveNumber(string text)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(text,@"[\d-]",string.Empty);
    }
```

**Note** :  I just want to remove first "-" only
example **"500 - my bag color is blue-brown"**
i expect the result is **"my bag color is blue-brown"** not **"my bag color is blue"** i need only remove the first "-" and number, Thanks

Comment: Please put the code **as text** in the question.

Comment: Try this Regex pattern `@"(\d+\s-\s)"`. Or maybe even without grouping.

Comment: Please update your question with input string and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Split()` function and `-` as a separator
Slipt Function returns a string array which contains substrings separated by a delimiter. In your, delimiter is `-`

```
private static string RemoveNumber(string text)
    {
        //return text.Split('-')[1].Trim(); Use of 1 as a Index may lead to an exception : Array IndexOutofBound 
        //Safer way to get last substring from an array
       return return text.Split('-').Take(2).LastOrDefault()?.Trim()
    }
```

If your input string contains multiple `-` and you want to remove only string before first `-` with delimiter the you can use `string.join` with `split`. Similar to

```
private static string RemoveNumber(string text)
{
    var result = string.Join("-", text.Split('-').Skip(1));
    return result;
}
```

`//Also Updated .Net fiddle`

Proof of Work : [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EoMZB6)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, i tried your suggestion ,  I get the result " I want to eat rice" , the sentence still contains white space, what i expect is "I want to eat rice"

Comment: @AlfatihKarim, You can use Trim() function to remove white spaces from the sentence

Comment: yes right but when the string is  "100 - I want - to eat rice" i get result "I want" what i expect "I want - to eat rice" @prasad Telkikar , i just want to remove first "-"

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method like this:

```
public string GetSubString(string input, char delim)
{
    var index = input.IndexOf(delim);

    return index == -1 ? input : input.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

Call Method like this:

```
string inputStr = "1 - The hello world";
Console.WriteLine(GetSubString(inputStr, '-'));
```